# Removing duplicates in a DeltaTable using Spark-SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

Let's say I have a table "people" with three columns: name(String), age(Integer), direction(String). The table contains duplicates with rows that are exactly the same. In order to remove the duplicates (but keeping one of them), I tried using the following code:

```sql
with sub as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as instance
    from vbzdev.mad.people
)
delete from sub where instance > 1;
```

So basically I'm trying to reproduce the behaviour of df.dropDuplicates() but using SQL syntax.

The code above throws the following error:

```
*com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.SparkDriverExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: [INTERNAL_ERROR] Unexpected table relation: Window [name#321, age#322, direction#323, row_number() windowspecdefinition(name#321, name#321 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS instance#317], [name#321], [name#321 ASC NULLS FIRST]*
```

I was able to fix my problem using the method described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61674476/how-to-drop-duplicates-in-delta-table) (Using MERGE INTO + Time Travel).

My question is: Why does the first method with a DELETE not work as it would in a normal relational DB? Does this have to do with the way DeltaTables store the data?

In case anyone is wondering, the following code returns the duplicate rows without a problem:

```sql
with sub as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as instance
    from vbzdev.mad.people
)
select * from sub where instance > 1;
```

As mentioned above, I'm trying to understand why using the "simpler" code with the window function does not work. My guess that the syntax of Spark-SQL does not allow for DELETE statements to be expressed this way, as the schema of the subquery does not match the schema of the original table.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673230/delete-duplicate-using-spark-sql)  did also not help, as I'm dealing with duplicate rows that have the exact same data, which means that the min() function would not work.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: can you use "SELECT DISTINCT col1,col2..... FROM YOURTABLE" ?

Comment: @JonScott I can, but in order to update the table I would need to CREATE TABLE AS SELECT DISTINCT.... This of course works, but I was trying to find a way of altering the table without creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

First, your query to select duplicates is a little off, you should actually be partitioning by all 3 columns:

```
with sub as (
select *, row_number() over (partition by name,age,direction order by name) as instance
from vbzdev.mad.people)
select * from sub where instance > 1;
```

however, in databricks, as you have found, you cannot delete from a CTE. (this is common across most databases)

There is another way, it works but it isn't elegant (I wonder if anyone can improve on this?).

1. Create a temp table with the duplicates.
2. Delete the duplicate keys (all sets of duplicates).
3. Insert just one set of the duplicates.
4. Delete the temp table.

So the code would look like this:

```
    create or replace table temp.del_then_insert_keys as 
    select array(name,age,direction) as del_key,
    name,age,direction,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By name,age,direction Order By name ) as rn  
    from vbzdev.mad.people 
    qualify rn>1 ;
    
    delete from vbzdev.mad.people where array(name,age,direction) in (select del_key from temp.del_then_insert_keys);
    insert into vbzdev.mad.people select name,age,direction from temp.del_then_insert_keys;
    
    drop table tempjs.del_then_insert_keys;
```

Comment: Thank you @Jon Scott! Your solution also works and is easier than the one with the MERGE statements :)